# Keep a datetime.date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format when using Flask's jsonify

Tags: python, json, date, datetime, flask

For some reason, the `jsonify` function is converting my `datetime.date` to what appears to be an HTTP date. How can I keep the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format when using `jsonify`?

```
test_date = datetime.date(2017, 4, 27)
print(test_date)  # 2017-04-27
test_date_jsonify = jsonify(test_date)
print(test_date_jsonify.get_data(as_text=True))  # Thu, 27 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT
```

As suggested in the comments, using `jsonify(str(test_date))` returns the desired format. However, consider the following case:

```
test_dict = {"name": "name1", "date":datetime.date(2017, 4, 27)}
print(test_dict) # {"name": "name1", "date":datetime.date(2017, 4, 27)}

test_dict_jsonify = jsonify(test_dict)
print(test_dict_jsonify.get_data(as_text=True)) # {"date": "Thu, 27 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT", "name": "name1"}

test_dict_jsonify = jsonify(str(test_dict))
print(test_dict_jsonify.get_data(as_text=True)) # "{"date": datetime.date(2017, 4, 27), "name": "name1"}"
```

In this case, the `str()` solution does not work.

Comment: Serialize it as a string?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: `jsonify(str(test_date))`

Comment: When you print an object, the object's `__str__` method is called, so that's what you see. If that's what you want to serialize and deserialize, call `str()` on your object.

Comment: That worked, thank you. However, I think I made the mistake of oversimplifying the case I'm dealing with. Usually when I jsonify a datetime.date, it is part of a dict with other elements, in which case this approach does not work. I have updated my question to better show the case I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

edit: this answer is now too old for Flask versions 2.3+.

for those newer versions, instead customize `json_provider_class`; reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=json_encoder#flask.Flask.json_provider_class

---

Following [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/) you can do this:

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from datetime import date


class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            if isinstance(obj, date):
                return obj.isoformat()
            iterable = iter(obj)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return list(iterable)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```

Route:

```
import datetime as dt

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    return jsonify({'now': now})
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the necessity of the try ... except ... else block compared to the other, simpler answer?

Comment: @MaxNoe: On review of the simpler approach, I don't think the extra checking is really necessary since -- as shown there -- simply checking for an instance of date should work. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: `app.json_encoder` is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3.

Comment: cannot import `JSONEncoder`, version `Flask-JSON 0.4.0`

Answer (score 25):

`datetime.date` is not a JSON type, so it's not serializable by default. Instead, Flask adds a hook to dump the date to a string in [RFC 1123](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) format, which is consistent with dates in other parts of HTTP requests and responses.

Use a custom JSON encoder if you want to change the format. Subclass [`JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) and set [`Flask.json_encoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder) to it.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

class MyJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, date):
            return o.isoformat()

        return super().default(o)

class MyFlask(Flask):
    json_encoder = MyJSONEncoder

app = MyFlask(__name__)
```

It is a good idea to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to transmit and store the value. It can be parsed unambiguously by JavaScript [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (and other parsers). Choose the output format when you output, not when you store.

> A string representing an RFC 2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

When you load the data, there's no way to know the value was meant to be a date instead of a string (since date is not a JSON type), so you don't get a `datetime.date` back, you get a string. (And if you did get a date, how would it know to return `date` instead of `datetime`?)

Answer (score 13):

Flask 2.2 shows a deprecation warning

`'JSONEncoder' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3. Use 'Flask.json' to provide an alternate JSON implementation instead.`

An update is needed to remove it and/or have it work in Flask 2.3+.  Another example from the Flask repository [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4692#issue-1303581666)

```
from datetime import datetime, date

from flask import Flask
from flask.json.provider import DefaultJSONProvider

class UpdatedJSONProvider(DefaultJSONProvider):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, date) or isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()
        return super().default(o)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json = UpdatedJSONProvider(app)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Sobingen.
Note that this code requires `import datetime` and then `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime` instead of `date` and `datetime`, and also it's presumably slightly faster to use `isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime))` in one call to `isinstance`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change [your app's `.json_encoder` attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder), implementing a variant of [`JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) that formats dates as you see fit.