# Python datetime UTC timezone is ruined with flask jsonify

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, jsonify

When UTC becomes GMT-0, it seems like flask jsonify doesn't adjust.

Example: server and database is in New york which is currently UTC-4.

When datetime has "2020-06-29 2:20:55-04" or "datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 28, 10, 20, 55, 613105, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)" it is all correct and understood.

However, jsonify takes in the former and spits out "Mon, 29 Jun 2020 06:20:55 GMT"

I guess jsonify is unable to tell that UTC is now GMT-0.

Please help

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663552/keep-a-datetime-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-when-using-flasks-jsonify